# Solr reducing search time

Tags: sql-server, performance, solr

I am a newbie to Solr. I've indexed a SQL Server table with about 14 columns, with 30 Million records into Solr. Indexing takes about 15 mins max. I store all the fields. So I don't have to go back to sql server to query. Basically I use solr as the database and directly search on it. There's no unique key but I've indexed only 1 column on which I search. **This column will always contain just 1 word.**

Each search on this column will not yield more than 200 records. In the response header - for every new search text -  I can see the QTime as 150, 200, 1350 ms some times. I want to bring this down to less than 50 ms.

"responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 150
  },

Can I do it without sharding just by making some small configuration changes?
Edited to add:
I am using Solr 5.3.0. I do not sort or use facets etc. My schema XML is:

```xml
<fields>        
    <field name="Postcode"                          type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />        
    <field name="PostTown"                          type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="true" />              
    <field name="DependantLocality"                 type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" />
    <field name="DoubleDependantLocality"           type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" />
    <field name="ThoroughfareName"                  type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" />
    <field name="ThoroughfareDescriptor"            type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" />
    <field name="ApprovedAbbreviation"              type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" />
</fields>
```

I've indexed on the post code and currently I only search thru the Solr Admin site like : Postcode:WA168GS

Thank you.

Comment: Too few information. How is your schema.xml? How is your solrconfig.xml? Which version of Solr are you using? How exactly do you query? Do you sort when querying? Do you use other features (facets, more like this, etc.) when submitting the query?

Comment: Did you check the docs about the topic? https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors or https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems

Comment: How do fast queries look like, how do slow queries look like? Probably your problem is related to [deep paging](http://solr.pl/en/2011/07/18/deep-paging-problem/) which can be solved with [proper pagination](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results).

Comment: Hey @Mihir please edit your post and write information like the portions of your schema.xml into the body of your questions. That is way easier and more pleasant to read :)

Answer (score 0):

The performance of the solr query can depends on couple of factor.

1. How much of the memory you provided to JVM (Heap) while starting the solr server. Now comes, how are using this memory. Solr provide you three different type of cache for caching the previous search results.

   - **filterCache :** Stores the filters built by Solr in response to filters added to queries. If you search for `velvet pants` with a filter parameter like `fq=category:apparel`, Solr will build a filter for that category and add it to its cache.
   - **queryResultCache :** Stores sets of document IDs returned by queries.
   - **documentCache :** This cache holds Lucene Document objects (the stored fields for each document).

So when you make a query with a `term` and some filter parameters, solr internally make two search, one for the actual term and another for each of filter criteria you have provided. Then merges the results. If any of the part is already available in cache then it will directly uses it from there. The `size`, `initialSize`, and `autowarmCount` parameter should be configured such way that you get the fast results. You can find more about [solr cache](https://teaspoon-consulting.com/articles/solr-cache-tuning.html) here.

2. You should keep you `openSearcher` flag to `false` in `autoCommit` configuration. Because it will open an new index searcher instance every time a hard commit happens. You should use `autoSoftCommit` configuration for loading the new index into searcher instead of hard commits.

You need to play around with these parameter to tune the solr for fast search queries.

Comment: Thanks guys!!! Have a long way to go with a lots of things in Solr. Will keep you updated.